# How may I align the equal signs of a multline equation and another equation that follows it?

Tags: align, multline

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\epsilon(r_1,...,r_n)\\= 
 sgn\prod_{\substack{1 \leq i<j \leq k}}(r_j-r_i)\times
 sgn\prod_{\substack{k+1 \leq i<j \leq n}}(r_i-r_j)\times
 sgn\prod_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq k\\
        k+1\leq j \leq n}}(r_i-r_j).
\end{multline*}

\begin{flalign*}
=&\epsilon(r_1,...,r_k)\times
\epsilon(r_k+1,...,r_n)\times
(-1)^{v_1+...+v_k}
&\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a single `align*` environment to typeset the entire expression.

Some additional comments on your LaTeX code. (i) The `\substack` instructions after the first two `\prod` directives don't do anything and should be omitted. (ii) You may wish to encase the subscript terms of the three `\prod` directives in `\mathclap` to bring about a nice and tight look of the material on first line. (iii) Don't type `...`; instead, type `\dots` and let LaTeX typeset the typographically appropriate ellipsis. (iv) Since "sgn" would appear to be a math operator, it should probably be typset in a roman (upright) font shape; I suggest declaring a math operator using the `\DeclareMathOperator` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\epsilon(r_1,\dots,r_n)
&=
 \sgn\prod_{\mathclap{1 \leq i<j \leq k}} (r_j-r_i)\times
 \sgn\prod_{\mathclap{k+1 \leq i<j \leq n}} (r_i-r_j)\times
 \sgn\prod_{\mathclap{\substack{1 \leq i \leq k\\ k+1\leq j \leq n}}} (r_i-r_j)\\
&=
 \epsilon(r_1,\dots,r_k)\times \epsilon(r_k+1,\dots,r_n)\times (-1)^{v_1+\dots+v_k}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to note that `mathtools` offers the `\smashoperator` command.

Comment: @Manuel - That's right. When used in displaymath mode, the outputs of `\sgn\prod_{\mathclap{1 \leq i<j \leq k}}(r_j-r_i)` and `\sgn\smashoperator{\prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq k}}(r_j-r_i)` are -- probably not coincidentally... -- identical.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a white space of the width you need for align both equations in different environments. In this case a`\quad` produces an *em* space (a space with the width of a capital em of the font in the size and weight you're using); that seems to be enough for your case.

From your own MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\epsilon(r_1,...,r_n)\\= 
 sgn\prod_{\substack{1 \leq i<j \leq k}}(r_j-r_i)\times
 sgn\prod_{\substack{k+1 \leq i<j \leq n}}(r_i-r_j)\times
 sgn\prod_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq k\\
        k+1\leq j \leq n}}(r_i-r_j).
\end{multline*}

\begin{flalign*}
\quad =&\epsilon(r_1,...,r_k)\times
\epsilon(r_k+1,...,r_n)\times
(-1)^{v_1+...+v_k} &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Avoid using consecutive display math environments.